# MySQL Connect Function doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I am trying to connect to my database, but it shows me error in the mysql_connect function.

The error is: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Connect.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Connect.php on line 12

The Connect file:

```
<?php  

$db_host = "localhost"; 
// Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_username = "root";  
// Place the password for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "";  
// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$db_name = "oscar"; 

// Run the connection here  
$con = mysql_connect("db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);
try 
{
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_pass);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

The text file:

```
<?php
// Connect to the MySQL database  
require "Connect.php"; 
echo "Success";
?>
```

Comment: what version of PHP is it? You know `mysql` functions are deprecated and removed from PHP 7+?

Comment: What is your php version. mysql_connect 
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

Comment: this line is wrong `$con = mysql_connect("db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");`

Comment: I am using php 7

Comment: then this code never work @Pixy_vxxc you have to use PDO or mysqli query

Comment: if you can upgrade to PHP7, then also upgrade to either MYSQLI or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `mysql_connect` is a deprecated function. Instead you should be using `mysqli_connect` read more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

The following code should work:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ...
 * Date: 5-12-2017
 * Time: 09:47
 * Database connection.
 */
?>
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'admin');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'your_database');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

why are you using mysql_connect and even PDO at the same time ? and mysql is deprecated so and vulnerable to sql injection.

only this code will connect to your database

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "root";
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "";
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "oscar";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_pass);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql function was deprecated in php 5.5.0. I have changed some changes in your code. $ symbol was added in mysqli connect statement.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db("$db_name", $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysqli`

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "root"; // Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "";// Place the password for the MySQL database here  
$db_name = "test";// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass,$db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This works perfectly.